# Embedding display expression inside asp.net tag

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that just have defined url constants, let's say it is called Urls. I am trying to access a constant in that class inside of a a LoginStatus tag as follows:

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl= <%= Urls.logout %>  CssClass="myButton" />
```

and obviously it isn't working. I know I can hardcode the string inside of the field, but I am trying to avoid that if possible. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
LogoutPageUrl="<%# Urls.logout %>"
```

The `#` is used to "bind" values to server side properties whereas the `=` is the same as a Response.Write() which in this case will just write some text to the markup

Comment: This is just a string constant.

Comment: Try the above with the #

Comment: Hmm, so it is compiling at least. However, now it is just redirecting to the login page, which signifies that the LoginStatus is seeing LogoutPageUrl as empty. Any ideas about that?